# Filter a list of strings with arbitrary condition

Tags: bash

Is there a way to leave only those strings that pass some (potentially any) condition? It is trivial to filter strings based on the fact that they themselves match some pattern (with grep). But what if I have a list of filenames and want to leave only those that are directories? What if I have a list of URL and want to leave only those that don't return 404 when I wget them? And so on. Is this kind of logic generalizable with bash?

Example:

```
$ echo $LIST
/home/me/a
/home/me/b
/home/me/b/some.jpg
$ echo $LIST | ${//%(!$SOME_FANCY_BASH_FILTERING_LOGIC_TO_CHECK_IF_THIS_IS_A_DIRECTORY&%^#}
/home/me/a
/home/me/b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about a list of potentially anything. If you have a list of filenames, you can easily create iterate over it with bash and select those which are directories. If you have a list of URL you can do the same to check which exist on the net. But, of course, the only part you can generalize is the iteration:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='
'
LIST='1
2
3
'
for I in $LIST
do
  if [ -d $I ]; then
    echo $I is a directory
  elif [ -f $I ]; then
    echo $I is a file
  fi
done
```

If you have two files named 1 and 3 and a directory named 2 the output will be:

```
1 is a file
2 is a directory
3 is a file
```

But if you have a list of URLs you will have to change the testing conditions inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this kind of logic generalizable with bash?

No.

To filter elements in `list`, however, leaving only those that are directories:

```
find  $list -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

Or,

```
for d in  $list; do [ -d "$d" ] && echo "$d"; done
```

Note that storing files in a shell variable, like `list`, as opposed to an array, will lead to problems if any of the file names contain a whitespace character.

Similarly, to filter a list of servers according to which are up (responding to pings):

```
$ server="yahoo.com google.com nonexistent.com"
$ for s in $server; do ping -qc1 "$s" >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$s" ; done
yahoo.com
google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own filter, like this:

```
# Filter a list of anything, based on predicate.
# $1: predicate, which take one argument (one item)
# $2: a collections of strings (IFS separated).
filter() {
    items=()
    for x in $2; do
        if $1 "$x"; then
            items+=("$x")
        fi
    done
    echo ${items[@]}
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
x() { [ $1 -gt 3 ]; }  # you can make any predicate
filter x "1 2 3 4 5"
-> 4 5
```

Alternatively, we could define it as:

```
filter() {
    while read line; do
        for x in $line; do
        if $1 "$x"; then
            echo "$x"
        fi
        done
    done
}
```

Which allows us to use it with pipes:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5 | filter x
-> 4
   5
```

Finally, both versions can be combined into one like this:

```
filter() {
    inner() (
        for x in $2; do
            $1 "$x" && echo "$x"
        done
    )
    if [ -t 0 ] && [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
        inner $1 "$2"
    else
        while read line; do
            inner $1 "$line"
        done
    fi
}
```